# Database locked in vb.net when trying to update data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello I have a simple method to update customer details in one of my database tables however when i try to update it an error occurs saying the database is locked. I have no idea how to fix this because my add and delete queries work just fine.
This is the error message:
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'database is locked
database is locked'

```
Public Sub updateguest(ByVal sql As String)
    Try

        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .CommandText = sql
            .Connection = con
        End With

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If result > 0 Then
            MsgBox("NEW RECORD HAS BEEN UPDATED!")
            con.Close()


        Else
            MsgBox("NO RECORD HASS BEEN UPDATDD!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

 Private Sub IbtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnUpdate.Click

    Dim usql As String = "UPDATE Customers SET fname = '" & txtFName.Text & "'" & "WHERE CustomerID ='" & txtSearchID.Text & "'"
    updateguest(usql)

End Sub
```

```
 Private Sub IbtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnSearch.Click
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim newds As New DataSet
    Dim newdt As New DataTable
    Dim msql, msql1 As String
    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    msql = "SELECT * FROM Customers Where Fname Like '" & txtSearchName.Text & "%'"
    msql1 = "SELECT * FROM Customers Where CustomerID '" & txtSearchID.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(msql, con)
    Dim cmd1 As New SQLiteCommand(msql1, con)

    Dim dt = GetSearchResults(txtSearchName.Text)
    dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = dt

    Dim mdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()



    If mdr.Read() Then


        If txtSearchName.Text <> "" Then
            sSQL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname LIKE'" & txtSearchName.Text & "%'"

            Dim con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd2 As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, con1)
            con1.Open()
            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2)
            da.Fill(newds, "customers")
            newdt = newds.Tables(0)
            If newdt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ToTextbox(newdt)
            End If
            dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = newdt
            con1.Close()
            txtSearchID.Clear()

        ElseIf txtSearchID.Text <> "" Then
            sSQL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustomerID ='" & txtSearchID.Text & "'"

            Dim con2 As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd2 As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, con2)
            con2.Open()
            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2)
            da.Fill(newds, "customers")
            newdt = newds.Tables(0)
            If newdt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ToTextbox(newdt)
            End If
            dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = newdt
            con2.Close()
            txtSearchName.Clear()


        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("No data found")
    End If


End Sub
   Private Sub IbtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnDelete.Click
    Dim dsql As String = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customerid = " & txtSearchID.Text & ""
    deleteme(dsql)
    updatedgv(dgvCustomerInfo)
    txtSearchID.Clear()
    txtSearchName.Clear()


End Sub
    Public Sub deleteme(ByVal sql As String)
    Try

        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .CommandText = sql
            .Connection = con
        End With

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If result > 0 Then
            MsgBox("NEW RECORD HAS BEEN DELTED!")
            con.Close()

        Else
            MsgBox("NO RECORD HASS BEEN DELTED!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()


    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the full and exact error message you are getting please?

Comment: Where are you initiating cmd and con?  Are you 100% sure of their state when you get to the updateguest methods?

Comment: Wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Is your CustomerID field a string type?

Comment: Database objects should be declared and disposed in the method where they are used.

Comment: @Mary How do I declare and dispose of the database objects, and my CustomerID is an INTEGER in the database and to search I use the .text

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a good start on keeping your database code separate from you user interface code. However, any message boxes should be shown in the user interface and any sql statements should be written in the data access code.

I used `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that database objects are closed and disposed. I used parameters to protect against sql injection. I am not too sure of the mapping of `DbType` types to Sqlite types. You might have to fool with that a bit. In you original Update statement you had the ID value in quotes. This would pass a string. When you use parameters, you don't have to worry about that or ampersands and double quotes. Just one clean string.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Public Function updateguest(FirstName As String, ID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim usql As String = "UPDATE Customers SET fname = @fname WHERE CustomerID = @ID;"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SQLiteCommand(usql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", DbType.String).Value = FirstName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        con.Open()
        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return Result
End Function

Private Sub IbtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnUpdate.Click
    Try
        Dim Result = updateguest(txtFName.Text, CInt(txtSearchID.Text))
        If Result > 0 Then
            MsgBox("New RECORD HAS BEEN UPDATED!")
        Else
            MsgBox("NO RECORD HAS BEEN UPDATDD!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there your code works however it works only before I do any sort of search query on the database, both update and delete work like that, however if i do do the search query and try to update or delete the records an error occurs saying that the database it locked.

Comment: Are you using a `Using...End Using` for every connection in the Update, Search and Delete?

Comment: Can I see the code for you Search and Delete? Add it as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Did you get rid of any connections declared at the form level?